# Does a Weapon Siphon make a weapon alchemical?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, objects

A [Weapon Siphon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1987) is an alchemical adjustment for a weapon.

If I load an Alchemist's Fire into it and I have [Burn it!](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=38), do I deal extra damage?
How much will it be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No.

Weapon Siphon reads:

> This set of tubing snakes down the striking surface of a weapon to
> deliver alchemical explosives. A single lesser alchemical bomb can be
> fitted to the weapon siphon as an Interact action. The bomb must be
> one that deals energy damage, such as an acid flask, alchemist's fire,
> bottled lightning, frost vial, or thunderstone. The next three attacks
> made with the weapon deal 1d4 damage of the bomb's damage type in
> addition to the weapon's normal damage. If the second and third
> attacks aren't all made within 1 minute of the first attack, the
> bomb's energy is wasted. **These attacks** never deal splash damage or
> other special effects of the bomb and **aren't modified by any abilities
> that add to or modify a bomb's effect.**

It's not the answer I wanted to give you at first, since it makes this combination of feats a tradeoff rather than a boon, but it seems pretty clear:
"These attacks [...] aren't modified by any abilities that add to or modify a bomb's effect."

You will only get an extra 1d4 fire damage from fitting an Alchemist's Fire bomb into the Weapon Siphon.

I can only assume these two feats are meant to lead down separate build paths, and I can't see any reason you'd ever load anything past a lesser bomb into the Weapon Siphon.

Comment: “_I can only assume these two feats are meant to lead down separate build paths_“ - more likely just an oversight borne of being released years apart. It’s the sort of thing I would happily house rule/handwave at my table. The intention of the exclusion on the siphon is clearly much more about excluding access to various higher level alchemist shenanigans on a melee attack.

Comment: That was my first instinct, to at least allow the feats to stack on the first shot, if not all three.
Perhaps you could say this comes down to specific beats general. But then the argument spills over into Fighter Power Attack + Cavalier Jousting, where the general rule for damage added per weapon die gets complicated.